# How would you do this cloth sim? I'm having trouble with the cloth not wiggling around after landing on the floor/cube base

Tags: cloth-simulation

Here's what I've done:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19vFh_NQxiJjMe6FzXpE3i3mPnR-lzdJO/view?usp=sharing

[image: the curtain falls]

How can I get it to fall with more natural weight and speed but also not move once hitting the ground?

Comment: I believe cloth objects are not meant to be solidified like that, so you may want to turn all the parameters down by half or something. Other than that, I think you should set the change endpoint  to have the simulation stop once it’s all fallen onto the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the cloth animation to be quicker/slower, just use the speed multiplier to get this effect.

[image]

Here as an example speed multiplier of 2:

[image]

If you don't want it move at the ground, just stop your animation earlier ;)

Here is your "old" cloth sim on the right, mine is on the left.

[image]

The big problem with your "more natural" is, that this word is very subjective. Everybody has another opinion about what is "natural".

Here are my cloth settings, if you are interested:

[image]

[image]

The main values i changed, were:

- speed multiplier (to speed the simulation up)
- friction (to have another look and make it stop earlier)
- stiffness and damping to make if more stiff ;)